# Using datetime how can I trigger a change based on the minute of the hour?

Tags: raspbian, python-3, pygame

I'm trying to edit a Python script that works perfectly - except I want to change one variable and I can't figure out how to do it.

The script plays a set of mp3 files in a directory. The script changes out the directory every day at 10 am and plays the files in the next directory (ie changes from directory 100 to 101 at 10am).

I want to change the switch over time from 10 to 10.30. My Python is limited - I've had several goes at it but can't make it bend to my will.

This is the script I'm using:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import sys
from time import sleep
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pygame

minDay = 1                                  #Start day
maxDay = 365                                #End Day
rootDirectory = '/media/pi/PHPLAYFILES/'    #Path to USB
changeHour = 10                             #Hour of day on which folder will be changed



def getDayOfYear():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    return (today - datetime.datetime(today.year, 1, 1)).days + 1

def getHourOfDay():
    return datetime.datetime.now().hour

def getRequiredDirectory():
    d = getDayOfYear()
    h = getHourOfDay()
    if d < minDay:
        print("Playlist hasn't started yet")
        sys.exit()
    elif d > maxDay:
        print("Playlist has finished")
        sys.exit()
    elif h < changeHour:
        return str(d - 1)+"/"
    else:
        return str(d)+"/"

currentDirectory = rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory()
pygame.mixer.init()
listOfFiles = [f for f in listdir(currentDirectory) if isfile(join(currentDirectory, f))]
index = 0

while True:
    if currentDirectory != rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory():
        index = 0
        currentDirectory = rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory()
        listOfFiles = [f for f in listdir(currentDirectory) if isfile(join(currentDirectory, f))]
    try:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(currentDirectory+listOfFiles[index%len(listOfFiles)])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    while (pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True) and (currentDirectory == rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory()):
        sleep(2)
        continue
    index = index + 1
```

That code works fine and does the change at 10. The following code is where I got to but just can't get it to switch over at 10.30 am.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import sys
from time import sleep
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pygame

minDay = 1                                  #Start day
maxDay = 366                                #End Day
rootDirectory = '/media/pi/PHPLAYFILES/'    #Path to USB
changeHour = 10                             #Hour of day on which folder will be changed
changeMinute = 30



def getDayOfYear():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    return (today - datetime.datetime(today.year, 1, 1)).days + 1

def getHourOfDay():
    return datetime.datetime.now().hour

def getMinuteOfHour():
    return datetime.datetime.now().minute

def getRequiredDirectory():
    d = getDayOfYear()
    h = getHourOfDay()
    m = getMinuteOfHour()
    if d < minDay:
        print("Playlist hasn't started yet")
        sys.exit()
    elif d > maxDay:
        print("Playlist has finished")
        sys.exit()
    elif h < changeHour:
        return str(d - 1)+"/"
    elif m < changeMinute:
        return str(d - 1)+"/"
    else:
        return str(d)+"/"

currentDirectory = rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory()
pygame.mixer.init()
listOfFiles = [f for f in listdir(currentDirectory) if isfile(join(currentDirectory, f))]
index = 0

while True:
    if currentDirectory != rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory():
        index = 0
        currentDirectory = rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory()
        listOfFiles = [f for f in listdir(currentDirectory) if isfile(join(currentDirectory, f))]
    try:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(currentDirectory+listOfFiles[index%len(listOfFiles)])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    while (pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True) and (currentDirectory == rootDirectory+getRequiredDirectory()):
        sleep(2)
        continue
    index = index + 1
```

Everything works fine except, when the minute rolls over to 30, it doesn't change and the log is just showing 'Module not recognized'.

Any help greatly received!

Comment: Ahh - that code didn't paste correctly and can't see where to edit...

Comment: This is a programming question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. May be better to ask at https://stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: I think @Ingo has a point re "off-topic", but viewed another way, many questions here are not *specific* to RPi.

Comment: Yeah - I see your point @Ingo. Using this exclusively on Raspberry Pi and that was my reference point. Will look elsewhere. Thanks.